# AP High latency, sometimes disconnection from network

Tags: switch, dhcp, spanning-tree

I have 6 APs connected to a desktop switch 
http://www.tp-link.com/lk/products/details/cat-4763_TL-SF1005D.html

MY APs are TPLINK TL-901WD

The desktop switch is connected to my main router Asus RTN66U running off Asus RWT Merlin Firmware(latest build)
https://www.asus.com/Networking/RTN66U/

Now I have been facing this issue, sometimes, I'm using one of the APs, the latency became really high, and disconnection happens. I restarted the router and AP then the problem goes away.

I'm not sure how to identify the problem, is it because of one of these?
1. DHCP lease time (i set to 7200)
2. Spanning Tree Protocol (disabled)
3. NAT Acceleration (disabled)<-Not sure why i cant seem to set it to Auto
 
4. Weak Desktop Switch 
5. I have turned on Per-IP monitoring and the database uses RAM(Asus RWT Merlin)
6. 10Mbps fibre line. (Even if theres not much usage, the problem still occurs)

My network have at least 50 concurrent users at peak hours.

Hope someone here can shed some light on my problem

Comment: The most likely problem you have is not on your list: wireless interference. You should look at what is happening in the airwaves. There are lots of things out of your control when it comes to wireless, and you may need to adjust your settings to accommodate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As like @Ron Maupin said, the wireless issue much likely cause by miss configured wireless AP.

If you sure your AP channel not configured properly (using auto mode), try to manage channel properly and see if the problem.

[He some material that may help you deploying more efficient wireless network.](http://www.slideshare.net/PeterSam67/advanced-location-based-services)

Comment: i see, thanks. I will check it out. I have found that when i browse some sites, it will have a long waiting time, then it will be back smooth for a few minutes and then another long waiting time.

Comment: is dns resolution a factor? I'm using google dns btw.

Comment: I think dns will not matter as I know google dns really good and never down. I once face this issue, in my workplace due to old PIC use auto channel that after I plan the channel using hexagonal method and distribute it with 1, 6 and 11 and the problem gone. [Selection Channel Frequency](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783011%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: How your AP design(channel, ssid etc), could you provide us with picture? maybe we can figure out your problem.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/s3s2c04n1/ here it is

Comment: Im not sure how to run tests on my AP wireless, i'm getting full bar reception here. its not the ap dropping connection but the internet connection keeps dropping. Example, when I'm browsing around sometimes theres this huge waiting time, and then if i do not use my ap for an hour or so, i come back, I load a website, i need to wait for a long time 10-15mins to load a site up and its not loaded completely.

Comment: it dosent happen when i directly access the internet from my main router wifi. asus rt66u

Comment: Did it also happen on local network e.g file sharing, local web server etc. If yes it might cause by either broadcast/multicast storm, loop back, collision due to mismatch port speed setting or duplex settings.

Comment: nope, local network is fine (if i connected to router's wifi). I will check each of the settings you mentioned. btw, i have changed my position of my AP, it was sticking to the wall with antenna up straight, i changed it , letting it to rest on a table while antenna are bend L shape. the latency and disconnection has been reduced. it still happens though but not that bad anymore.